# PHP, Error in Shopping Cart Program

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a Shopping Cart in PHP. It worked fine. But then I removed all items from the Shopping Cart and it failed. I think it has something with the session, but I not complete sure.
I am getting this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpshop\index.php on line 85
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  244096  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0017  255352  mysqli_fetch_array ( )
```

[I used this Shopping cart tutorial to build this program.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-shopping-cart-with-php-and-mysql--net-5144)

cart.php code:

```
<?php



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val)
    {
        if($val==0)
        {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);


        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
        }
    }

}

?>

<h1>View cart</h1>
<a href="index.php?page=products">Go back to products page</a>
<form method="post" action="index.php?page=cart">

    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Items Price</th>
        </tr>

        <?php

        $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value)
        {
            $sql.=$id.",";
        }




        $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
```

**line 85 about here** --->  $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

```
        $totalprice=0;

        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if($numrows == 0)
        {

            header("Location: index.php");

        }

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'];
            $totalprice+=$subtotal;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?>" /></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?>$</td>
                <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity']*$row['price'] ?>$</td>
            </tr>
            <?php

        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Total Price: <?php echo $totalprice ?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Cart</button>
</form>
<br />
<p>To remove an item, set it's quantity to 0. </p>
```

index.php

```
<?php




session_start();









require("includes/connection.php");
if(isset($_GET['page'])){

    $pages=array("products", "cart");

    if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {

        $_page=$_GET['page'];

    }else{

        $_page="products";

    }

}
else{

    $_page="products";

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <title>Shopping cart</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="main">

        <?php require($_page.".php"); ?>

    </div><!--end main-->

    <div id="sidebar">

        <h1>Cart</h1>
        <?php

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

            $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product IN (";

            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value)
            {
                $sql.=$id.",";
            }







            $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
            $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {

                ?>
                <p><?php echo $row['name'] ?> x <?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_product']]['quantity'] ?></p>
                <?php

            }
            ?>
            <hr />
            <a href="index.php?page=cart">Go to cart</a>
            <?php

        }
        else
        {

            echo "<p>Your Cart is empty. Please add some products.</p>";

        }

        ?>

    </div><!--end sidebar-->

</div><!--end container-->

</body>
</html>
```

products.php

```
<?php



if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add")
{

    $id=intval($_GET['id']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){

        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;

    }

    else
    {

        $sql_s="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_product={$id}";

        $query_s=mysqli_query($con,$sql_s);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_s)!=0)
        {
            $row_s=mysqli_fetch_array($query_s);

            $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['id_product']]=array
            (
                "quantity" => 1,
                "price" => $row_s['price']
            );


        }
        else
        {

            $message="This product id it's invalid!";

        }

    }

}

?>

<h1>Product List</h1>

<?php
if(isset($message)){
    echo "<h2>$message</h2>";
}
?>
<table>
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?>$</td>
            <td><a href="index.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>">Add to cart</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php

    }

    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You've included way too much code here; if the issue is with index.php, then you probably don't need to include the other files.

Comment: That said - you're generating the cart by using an IN clause in your SQL statement. But if your cart is empty, then you'll be generating an invalid SQL statement (`WHERE id_product IN () ... `). So just check to see if `$_SESSION['cart']` is empty before running that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment of

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

is failing and returning a boolean value of FALSE. This is because `$con` is not being set properly.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

so, you are passing FALSE into mysqli_fetch_array as the $query

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
```

This is causing the error you reported

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpshop\index.php on line 85**

Comment: This is almost certainly being caused because the SQL query isn't working, rather than it being an issue with the connection. But given the lack of error checking, it's anyone's guess.

Comment: Thank you for all your help guys :0)

Comment: I just added  this to check if the session not is empty. Now it works!` && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])`